# How can I select records which has same value?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table. This table includes customers and products. Sample data is is in below.

| Customer Name | Product |
| --- | --- |
| John | laptop |
| John | telephone |
| John | laptop |
| Kevin | laptop |
| Kevin | laptop |
| Kevin | laptop |

I want to select customer who chose all their products with a  laptop so This case I want to select Kevin because he selected laptop his all products. I dont want to select john because he selected laptop but also select telephone not all product of john laptop.

How can I do this in tsql?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify the expected result in the same format.

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation in the having clause

```sql
SELECT [Customer Name]
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY [Customer Name]
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Product <> 'laptop' THEN 1 END) = 0
-- alternatively
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Product = 'laptop' THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name
FROM Customers
WHERE (SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE Product = 'telephone') != Name
GROUP BY NAME;
```

This should help you, it might not be the final asnwer but it shall provide enough for you to figure it out in some edge cases